# Fastest way to perform operations on numpy array billions of times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code has below goals:

1.) Given 2 numpy arrays a1 and a2 (composed only of 0,1's) find index locations of 0's in a1 and a2.

2.) Find matching index positions if any between array a1 and a2

3.) Calculate a metric

a1 array shape = 2161

a2 array shape = 2161

e.g.

a1 = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1]

a2 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0]

index of 0's in a1 = idx_a1[0,3,5]

index of 0's in a2 = idx_a2[2,3,6]

common 0's indexes b/w a1 and a2 = 3

function_1 performs step1 and step2 and step3

function1_iterations repeats function_1 after randomly shuffling a1 and repeating metric calculation 1000 times. This is for the purpose of finding if metric is statistically significant.

I perform below code on 100 million array pairs, multiprocessed on 256 cores. Best runtime for 100 million array pairs is about 40 mins. Is there any way I can make it significantly efficient? I need to be running this on billions of array pairs.

My code below is the fastest that I could come up with some help from people from codereview earlier:

```
def function_1(self,a1, a2):
        
       
    
        event_index1, = np.where(a1 == 0)
        event_index2, = np.where(a2 == 0)
        n1, = event_index1.shape
        n2, = event_index2.shape
    
        if n1 == 0 or n2 == 0:
            return 0, 0
    
        n_matches, = np.intersect1d(event_index1, event_index2, assume_unique=True,).shape
        
        c_ij = n_matches/2

    
 
        metric_1= (c_ij *2) / math.sqrt(n1 * n2)
   

        return metric_1

    
    
    def function1_iterations(self,a1,a2,repeat = 1000,original_metric1):
        
        list_metric1 = []
        a1_copy = copy.deepcopy(a1)

        
        for i in range(0,repeat):
            np.random.shuffle(a1_copy)    # shuffle bits in array and recalculate 1000 times  
            
            metric_1 = self.function_1(a1= a1_copy, a2 = a2) 
            list_metric1.append(metric_1)
        list_metric1= np.array(list_metric1)
        
      
        significance_val = len(np.where(list_metric1>= [original_metric1])[0])/repeat
        
        
        return significance_val
```

Comment: you should identify which part of your code is the slowest and simplify your question to try to optimize that one first

Comment: Wait, you're setting `c_ij = c_ji = n_matches/2`, and then only using `c_ij` and `c_ji` to compute `c_ij + c_ji`? Why would you do that? (It's not the bottleneck, but it's bizarre.)

Comment: @mozway Should I have profiled the code line by line for this? I used timeit to test performance of the code snippet

Comment: If you goal is to optimize to run on large datasets, yes probably

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first part of your code, your method to find the common indices is not efficient, rather use boolean operations:

```
# setup
np.random.seed(0)
a1 = np.random.choice([0,1], 1000000)
a2 = np.random.choice([0,1], 1000000)


# your option
event_index1, = np.where(a1 == 0)
event_index2, = np.where(a2 == 0)
n_matches, = np.intersect1d(event_index1, event_index2, assume_unique=True,).shape
n_matches

# output: 250947
# 74.8 ms ± 2.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


# boolean operations
n_matches = ((a1==0)&(a2==0)).sum()

# output: 250947
# 1.98 ms ± 23.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks,used timeit to compare to original code. Repeated on 100,000 array pairs of my data. Performace is the same for some reason. Below timeit runtime in seconds. I used timeit.repeat for this. Orig = [1.8448893700000013,1.9183033499999993,1.9350099100000022,1.8952869600000013
,1.881331590000002,1.8508602699999983,1.8069528700000035,1.9085916200000042,1.8852551699999993,1.8711837899999977]   mozway_run = [1.9086207299999998,1.8873793100000007,1.9485812600000003,1.9337501099999996,1.8837477899999997,1.78254278,1.7270117499999997,1.6787742400000014,1.7728193299999986,2.0007923199999995]

Comment: this likely means you have another bottleneck (not that this wouldn't further improve your code once this bottleneck is found)

Comment: you should probably ask your question on code review, but make sure to provide better formatted code (and a reproducible way to generate large input)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to perform an index comparison. Direct matching of array values against zero should provide a faster result:

```
def function_1(a1,a2):
    z1 = a1.size - np.sum(a1) # number of zeros in a1
    z2 = a2.size - np.sum(a2) # number of zeros in a2
    cs = min(a1.size,a2.size) # common size
    return np.sum((a1[:cs]|a2[:cs])==0)/math.sqrt(z1*z2) # measure
```

*Note that this assumes that a1 and a2 can be of varying sizes and have a different number of zeros each time.  The calling function (function_iterations) does not produce these conditions. In that case a1 an a2 will always be the same size from one iteration to the next and have the same number of zeros.  This means that the calculations could be simplified by computing the denominator only once and supplying it as an argument (or perform the division separately from counting matches).*

There is very little parallelism in the function1_iterations() function, so that is where most of the time is spent.

In order to benefit from parallel computations, you would need to efficiently build a matrix of shuffled bits and process them all as a whole using numpy operations (instead of a Python loop with thousands of iterations).

here's an example of how you could generate a new metrics list with better parallelism:

```
def computeMetrics(a1,a2,repeat = 1000):

    z1 = a1.size - np.sum(a1) # number of zeros in a1
    z2 = a2.size - np.sum(a2) # number of zeros in a2
    cs = min(a1.size,a2.size) # common size

    # shuffle matrix of a1 copies
    a1s = np.repeat(a1[None,:],repeat,axis=0)  
    a1s = np.apply_along_axis(np.random.choice,1,a1s,a1.size,replace=False)

    # compute metric for each shuffled row (with parallelism)
    return np.sum((a1s[:,:cs]|a2[:cs])==0,axis=1)/math.sqrt(z1*z2)
```

Output:

```
a1 = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,1])
a2 = np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1,0])
print(computeMetrics(a1,a2,10))

[0.33333333 0.66666667 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.66666667
 0.         0.66666667 0.33333333 0.33333333]

a1 = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0])   
a2 = np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1,0])            
print(computeMetrics(a1,a2,10))

[0.21821789 0.21821789 0.21821789 0.43643578 0.43643578 0.43643578
 0.65465367 0.21821789 0.21821789 0.21821789]
```

Using 100M repeats on your actual data would probably require too much memory but you could break that down into chunks of 1M and concatenate the results.

```
computeMetrics(a1,a2,1000)      takes 0.044 sec on my laptop
computeMetrics(a1,a2,1_000_000) takes 48 seconds
```